# Create an animation from left to the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create an animation which will make a menu appear from the left side of the screen. This animation should be started on a click on a button.
The content of the menu should recover **`55%`** of the width of the main page.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mtoypc/q2sjvdLe/)

In the previous link you can the the menu and the button to move left. At the beginning the menu (with the "link" elements) should be hidden and the button `.glyhicon` should be at the very left of the page.
On click on this button the menu and the button should move to the right and recover **`55%`** of the main page. 
The problem is I don't know how to do this. (I managed to move the menu by changing the structure but I couldn't move the button.)
Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="left-menu">
    <div id="map-menu" class="test">
      <nav class="menu_content">
        <ul>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="icon-menu" class="test">
      <button id="button_menu" class="js-menu menu" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
#left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#map-menu, #icon-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu {
  background: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 2rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.menu_content{
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eaeaea;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.1, 0.34, 0.91);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.1, 0.34, 0.91);
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.1, 0.34, 0.91);
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.1, 0.34, 0.91), -webkit-transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.56, 0.1, 0.34, 0.91);
  padding-top: 6.2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-open nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}

.menu_content ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu_content ul li {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.menu_content ul li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

javascript :

```
var isActive = false;

$('.js-menu').on('click', function() {
    if (isActive) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#left_menu').removeClass('menu-open');
    /*$('#button_menu').removeClass('move-right');
    $('#button_menu').addClass('move-left');*/
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#left_menu').addClass('menu-open');
    /*$('#button_menu').removeClass('move-left');
    $('#button_menu').addClass('move-right');*/
    }

    isActive = !isActive;
});
```

Could you help me to adapt or redo the animation please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS solution without any javascript by making use of the `:checked` status of a hidden checkbox with `display:none`, the `label` for that checkbox should be outside the `#left-menu` element so it is possible to target it using `~`:

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/g6ptq2yt/)

```css
#button_menu {
  display: none;
}
.glyphicon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/06_menu_stack-2-128.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#left-menu {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  width: 55%;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#button_menu:checked + .glyphicon {
  left: 55%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ #left-menu {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.menu_content ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu_content ul li {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.menu_content ul li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="button_menu" class="js-menu">
<label for="button_menu" class="glyphicon"></label>
<div id="left-menu">
  <div id="map-menu" class="test">
    <nav class="menu_content">
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

and here's a simple jQuery solution, where basically we have a variable as a triggering flag `toggleFlag`, if its value is `true` the `left` value is `0`, while if the triggering flag value is `false` then the `left` value is `-55%` -*which is the menu width as the op said it takes `55%` of the screen*-, then we animate the `.left-menu` dependign on the left value, and we need to *negate* the value of the triggering flag.

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/g6ptq2yt/3/)

```js
var menuIcon = $('.glyphicon'),
  leftMenu = $('#left-menu'),
  toggleFlag = true;

menuIcon.on('click', function() {
  var leftVal = (toggleFlag) ? '0' : '-55%';
  $('#left-menu').animate({'left': leftVal }, 700);
  toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-round/700/06_menu_stack-2-128.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#left-menu {
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  left: -55%;
  width: 55%;
  top: 50%;
}
.slideIt {
  color: red;
}
.menu_content ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu_content ul li {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.menu_content ul li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-menu">
  <span class="glyphicon"></span>
  <div id="map-menu" class="test">
    <nav class="menu_content">
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I solved my problem by adapting the one in JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There a couple things with your example and fiddle, to start it helps to have jquery loaded in the fiddle to mess around.

Next `isActive` is not only not defined but unnecessary

```
if (isActive) {
```

should be replaced by

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
```

and

```
isActive = !isActive;
```

can be removed completely

next you becareful with your underscores and hyphens

```
$('#left-menu') != $('#left_menu')
```

Please also wrap it all in a document ready so it can be attached when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code
});
```

so with the fixes you can have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.js-menu').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('#left-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#left-menu').addClass('menu-open');
    }
  });
});
```

Now to move your button, the problem is you're adding the transform to the `<nav>` in the `menu-open` class with :

```
.menu-open nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

So one way to fix that would be to also add it to your button

```
.menu-open #icon-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55%);
  transform: translateX(55%);
}
```

OR

```
.menu-open .active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55%);
  transform: translateX(55%);
}
```

I'll leave you to do the slide animation and so on.

There's a couple ways to make it better than this but with what you have for now this'll probably help you get a start on it? Maybe?